# SGE Cluster - script fails after submission - works in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

I have a script that I am trying to submit to a SGE cluster (on Redhat Linux). The very first part of the script defines the current folder from the full CWD path, as a variable to use downstream:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -A username
#$ -M user@server
#$ -j y
#$ -m aes
#$ -N test
#$ -o test.log.txt

echo 'This is a test.'
result="${PWD##*/}"
echo $result
```

In bash, this works as expected:

CWD:

```
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/user/test
```

Run script:

```
-bash-4.1$ bash test.sh
This is a test.
test
```

When I submit the job to the cluster:

```
-bash-4.1$ qsub -V test.sh
```

and examine the log file:

```
This is a test.
Missing }.
```

Does anyone know why the job submission is saying "Missing } " when it works right from the command-line? I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. What I would recommend to try is to run the command `qrsh` to log to a node through SGE. Then run your script from there. It doesn't do exactly the same thing but I may help you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The posix standard for batch schedulers requires them to ignore the #! line and instead use either a shell configured into the cluster or one selected by the -S option of qsub.  The default is usually csh. So adding something like `#$ -S /usr/bin/bash` into the script will cause it to be interpreted by bash.

Alternatively you could convince the cluster admin to change the queues to unix_behavior from posix_compliant.